# Route requests for the same room to the same server which uses web sockets when implementing a load balancer

Tags: websocket, socket.io, load-balancing, web-deployment, haproxy

I have an online whiteboard where users connect to the same room depending on the last part of the url where the room name is present. The urls are dynamic and is created per new room.

Eg: https://.../room/123456

I use web sockets to communicate between client and server. The users are subscribed to the same channel based on the room name. I'm going to implement a **load balancer** server to handle the traffic. Since we create a session on the server for that particular room it is essential that every user in the room is directed to that **particular server**. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think creating a proxy with the `uri` [balancing method](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#4.2-balance) may be what you're looking for.  By default, it will distribute traffic based on the hash of your URL path.

```
backend bk_whiteboard
    balance uri
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mweiss. Any idea on how to handle the websockets?

Comment: @YasithPrabuddhaka HAProxy has a good article on how to optimize your configuration for websocket https://www.haproxy.com/blog/websockets-load-balancing-with-haproxy/. Is this what you're looking for?